# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler.configureJobConf

Tags: java, mongodb, hive

I am getting 'java lang AbstactMethodError'.
Anyone can please help me.
I am unable to find out reason behind it.
Thanks in advance`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler.configureJobConf(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/plan/TableDesc;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)V`

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

Comment: this error is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.This should have been caught at compile time itself see this for help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

Comment: Thanks but How to remove this error?

Comment: Its most likely incompatible versions of Hive and the mongodb-hadoop connector - have you checked the mongodb-hadoop readme to ensure they are compatible?